# Linking to pages within custom profileMenu component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningnavigation

Friends --

I've created a custom `profileMenu.cmp` where I'm iterating Menu Items and want to link to a specified page, but can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

```
<aura:attribute name="actionMenuOptions" type="String[]" default="Menu Item 1, Menu Item 2" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navigationService" />

<ui:menuList class="actionMenu" aura:id="actionMenu">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.actionMenuOptions}" var="itemLabel">
    <ui:actionMenuItem label="{!itemLabel}" click="{!c.handleClick}" />
  </aura:iteration>
</ui:menuList>
```

And want to link to an internal page in my community `profileMenuController.js`

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var source = event.getSource();
        var label = source.get("v.label");

        console.log('label'+label);
        if(label=="Menu Item 1") {
            // Do work
            cmp.find("navigationService").navigate({ 
                type: "standard__webPage", 
                attributes: { 
                    url: '/page' 
                } 
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated. This seems to suit my needs.

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var source = event.getSource();
        var label = source.get("v.label");
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");

        console.log('label'+label);
        if(label=="Menu Item 1") {
            // Do work
            urlEvent.setParams({
              "url": "/menu-item-1"
            });
        }
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
```